# Can I download folders from Google Drive to my Android device

Tags: downloading, google-drive

I have recently saved a lot of music and pictures onto my google drive and now I would like to save them from there straight onto my SD Card (in my S4). I know if I press on the file for a few seconds it gives me the option to save it but like I said I have a lot on there (roughly 4000 pictures and songs) so to do it all individually will take a lot of time I don't really have...

So my question - is there a way to download everything in a folder at once or is there a "select all" option in google drive?

Comment: Similar question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40569/is-there-a-way-to-download-the-files-stored-on-google-drive-to-an-android-device

Comment: Worrked for me using Filigree Explorer on Android. Transfered the file to my phone. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

You can alternatively use the browser and go to [drive.google.com/] and run the site in desktop mode. There, you can use the bar that's just under the search bar. Once you have navigated to the desired folder, go back to the bar I mentioned before, and tap your folder's name in the bar. After doing so, you will find a dropdown menu that will have options in it. There should be an option that says "Download", with a down arrow to the left of it. Tap that, and you're off to downloading the folder you had uploaded.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 9):

Okay I have found a third party app that lets me copy everything from Google drive in one easy step - **Astro File Manager** - it's a free app on play store, works brilliantly for this as you can select everything in the drive and simply copy it over to your SD Card.

This app will also work with dropbox and other cloud services.

Comment: A plus for Astro File Manager is that it can show you the size of a folder on Google drive

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for a third party app. You can explore your Google drive storage like you can your internal storage from your phone's settings app. There you can then copy even folders to your internal storage

- Open Files.
- Press on the button to open the side menu.
- Select Drive.
- Go to the folder you wish to download.
- Long press the folder.
- Press on the 3 dots button at top right.
- Press on Copy to...
- Go to where you want to copy it on your phone.
- Press on the Copy button at bottom right.

Comment: Please explain how will you do. You can use screenshots too.

Comment: Can't find any `Copy to...` button on the app.

Comment: Drive doesn't show up in the app (may of done in the past) :(

Comment: No `Copy too...`. Android 10.

Comment: Nope. Google Files mysteryously won't show the Drive... resorting to the old fast way of copying to a usb stick and reading on the phone with an adapter - always works.. clunky but works every time.

Answer (score 3):

Google drive for android currently doesn't provide this option !

you could use file manager like 'ES file explorer' for android

you can connect to your google drive from it and easily copy folders

Comment: Why is android apps still in the pre-history of file management. I can't understand. I just want to add 10 music files from my google drive to VLC, on my android phone and there isn't a way. I'm switching my music to Dropbox, which I can work with.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.android-hilfe.de/thema/dateien-von-google-drive-auf-android-geraet-herunterladen.298866/) quick work around:

1. Install a small app called "Send to SD card".
2. In Drive select the file you want to download and click on "send..." > "Send to SD Card".
3. Now select a folder and copy the file.

Comment: this only allows you to send files. the question asks how to send entire folders.